# Criminal act between borders

Tags: criminal-law, constitutional-law

What happens if the inhumanity crimes conducted between two counties border when the citizen of country A kills a citizen of country B then leave to country A,what country has power of arest and which law directs?

Comment: It also isn't entirely clear if this question concerns a crime that is actually committed across the border (for example a shooter in one country shooting someone in another country), or a crime committed in one country by someone who flees to another country.

Comment: Also, generally a "border" is a line with no depth. You cannot commit a crime "between" two country's borders in most case because the borders will generally directly abut each other.